# Adding custom HTTP headers to nginx X-Accel-Redirect via express.js

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I am serving restricted downloads in nodejs using X-Accel-Redirect with nginx. I am trying to send the custom header in the non standard HTTP header Header1,Header2 to the X-Accel-Redirect request. But this is not working.

below the rails snippet used to do the redirection

```
  var  httpHeaders={'NonStandardHeader':"Hello"}
  var headers = Object.assign({ 'X-Accel-Redirect': url }, httpHeaders);
     res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end();
```

nginx.conf

```
 location /microservice/file {
   alias /protected;
  internal;
}
 location /microservice/memcache {
  ... 
  internal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for the question.passing querystring to internal location

---

nodejs:

```
var    url='/microservice/file/a1.json?p=23x&e=22d';
   res.writeHead(200, { 'X-Accel-Redirect': url });
res.end();
```

---

nginx.conf

```
location /microservice/file {
   alias /protected;
    add_header 'NonStandardHeader' $arg_p;
      expires $arg_e;

  internal;
}
```